# Set up bash inside self-hosted Windows agents in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Microsoft's [own documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software) provides the links to the images used for various operating systems, on top of which Microsoft-hosted agents get created.

For Windows Server 2019, the [link](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md) shows `bash` as one of the tools included, and it also mentions WSL1 (Windows Subsystem for Linux v1) as installed. And it works just as expected, with [Bash tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) running just fine inside Azure DevOps pipelines.

We're currently in the process of setting up our own self-hosted Windows agents, and we're looking for this capability as well. But to my knowledge, having Linux tools such as `bash` working on Windows requires 1) WSL installed and 2) a Linux distribution installed *per a specific user*. The procedure for deploying on Windows Server is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-on-server).

WSL doesn't currently have multiple-user support (GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5151)) and trying to run Linux tools as `LOCAL SYSTEM` presents [challenges of their own](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4803). **So in this context, how does the image used by the Microsoft-hosted Azure DevOps agents allow them to seamlessly run `bash`?**

I heard about Cygwin, and know that it can provide similar functionality, but for now I'm trying to get `bash` configured similar to how it's done on Microsoft's own hosted agents.

Answer (score 1):

As of this time, however, I think it is not supported running bash in Azure DevOps self-hosted Windows agent.

The Bash task runs on the agent as the user "NT Authority \ Network Service".  However, we cannot install Linux distribution for this user. It will show that the user haven't logged in.

But for Microsoft, its virtual machines should have a specific user from whom bash starts rather than the default NT Authority \ Network Service.

Comment: I'm not sure a Linux distro is installed in the process of deploying the images on the Microsoft-hosted agents, or at least I couldn't find that step in the repository. I did found some symbolic links created towards the Git Bash utility, but nothing *from* bash.exe. One example here https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/ff9f3f0a8bc69e64fad8790abcc61ff266277b76/images/win/scripts/Installers/Configure-Shell.ps1